# Eclipse IDE: CamelCase navigation within words via CTRL+left/right in XML editor

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, editor

In the Eclipse Java editor, using CTRL+left/right lets the cursor stop at every upper case character within a word. In the XML editor, the cursor jumps over the whole word.

Is there an option (I'm using Eclipse Indigo) to activate CamelCase navigation in the Eclipse XML editor, so it behaves like the Java editor?

Thanks a lot for your help!